# Is it possible to run a Docker image while mounting NTFS symlinks?

Tags: c#, docker, symlink, ntfs

I'm trying to incorporate Docker into my workflow developing web apps using C#, but I stumbled across an issue trying to use it.

Long story short, I run Windows, and I have an unusual storage setup on my computer. Normally, nuget packages get downloaded into a cache in the `.nuget\packages` folder in the user's profile. For space reasons I had to symlink that folder to a separate hard disk, so `.nuget\packages` redirects to another drive.

It works well for all my regular development so far, but it seems that Docker really doesn't like the symlink. I'm guessing that maybe it doesn't rely on transparent OS access to a filesystem, and that's why it refuses to mount it, but... Is there a way to keep my Symlink, but maybe tell Docker from inside Visual Studio to use the original directory, or is there some other kind of workaround?

Comment: You can change the cache folder location so you won’t need a symlink - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders

Comment: As far as I know there is a mechanism to point from a docker image to a path outside the docker image. Can't tell you how. I played with it a while ago. That's how a docker image can be set to use a database file.